# btrfs volume is full

Tags: disk-usage, btrfs, veracrypt

Ubuntu says that my btrfs partition is full when it should not be full.

[image]

It clearly says under *Contents:* that there is only one file with size 912.7GB, however 997,9 GB are used and I don't know what they are used for. The file is an encrypted VeraCrypt volume.

There are no other files or hidden files:

```
root@muhbuntu:/media/itssme/MrData# ls -a
.  ..  storage.cryp
```

brtfs shows that a total of 927GiB are available (which is about 995GB). Metadata is only 1.97GiB, so it's not the problem like in a lot of other similar posts on this topic.

```
root@muhbuntu:/home/itssme# btrfs filesystem df /media/itssme/MrData/
Data, single: total=927.50GiB, used=927.27GiB
System, DUP: total=32.00MiB, used=128.00KiB
Metadata, DUP: total=1.97GiB, used=996.83MiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

Answer (score 3):

From what I read so far, VeraCrypt uses all space that it got allocated when used as a File Container.

As seen in this below:
[image: screenshot of VeraCrypt Volume Creation Wizard]
<sub>(source: [securityinabox.org](https://securityinabox.org/media/veracrypt-win-en-v01-113-volume_creation.png))</sub>

you should eventually consider using the partition / drive instead of a File Container.

Comment: yes its a veracrypt volume

Comment: @Melebius is that better so? and i hope it helps to explain why it is described as full.

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer. Don’t hesitate to remove the outdated contents of your post while editing. I’ve done it this time for you.